# Is it correct to use "humble connaissance" in a cover letter?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

I've seen in Internet so many cover letters using this expression:

> Je porte à votre humble connaissance que je suis titulaire…

I know that *humble* in French means *modeste*, just like in English. The cover letter is addressed to the hiring personal, maybe the manager itself. So I don't understand how can we address e.g. the manager by such degrading terms.

Comment: So many cover letters? Google only knows 3 pages with that expression, which by the way should never be used that way, as you guessed https://www.google.com/search?hl=fr&q=%22Je%20porte%20%C3%A0%20votre%20humble%20connaissance%22

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not searching in Internet using only google!!!

Comment: Yahoo! offers 3 results : https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=Ammgn1UWqzqmjUhgNVoeUbmbvZx4?p=%22Je+porte+%C3%A0+votre+humble+connaissance%22&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-dummy_1&fp=1 ; DuckDuckGo found none : https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Je+porte+%C3%A0+votre+humble+connaissance%22

Comment: I'm honestly interested in links where such a bad usage of the expression is actually presented as correct.

Answer (score 3):

> - À mon humble connaissance, cette référence n'existe pas dans le livre cité.
> - À mon humble avis il  doit être possible d'agir différemment.

Dans ces expressions, c'est *moi* qui est *humble* c'est-à-dire qui respecte, qui considère l'autre comme supérieur à moi dans son domaine d'excellence ; et je m'autorise à donner un avis, une opinion, une idée (en toute humilité) qui peut être contredite.

Ce n'est donc pas *l'autre*, celle ou celui à qui on s'adresse qui doit être humble, surtout si ses connaissances sont par essence plus profondes que les miennes... puisqu'il connaît le poste pour lequel je postule.

Par expérience, il est déconseillé de s'aplatir ou de jouer les *je sais tout* lorsqu'on postule pour un poste, deux attitudes extrêmes qui seront rejetées par le recruteur... et donc ne pas lui demander en plus d'être humble!

Une lettre rédigée avec la mention portée dans votre question ne sera pas lu plus loin et ira directement à la poubelle, d'autant plus rapidement que le poste à pourvoir est un poste qualifié.

D'ailleurs les diplômes ne sont pas à mentionner dans la lettre d'accompagnement, mais dans le CV (Curriculum Vitae).